# How to mock external dependency in typescript using jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am hopelessly trying to mock firebase admin dependency in typescript for unit testing.

My actual function is as below

```
import {auth} from 'firebase-admin';

async validateUser(payload: string): Promise<User> {
  try {
    const resp = await auth().verifyIdToken(payload, true);

    return await this.userService.findByUsername(resp.email);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
 }
}
```

I am trying to test the `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(payload, true)` by mocking the `admin` function. I attempted the test code like below

```
import {auth} from 'firebase-admin';

jest.mock('firebase-admin');

const mockedAuth = auth as jest.Mock;

mockedAuth.mockReturnValue({
  verifyIdToken: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
});
```

but I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockReturnValue' of undefined`

if I am understanding correctly, I am mocking the entire `firebase-admin` package by calling `jest.mock('firebase-admin')`. So I would expect to be able to call `mockReturnValue` and again mock the `verifyIdToken` function within the auth function. However, I am not even able to call `mockReturnValue` because weirdly it doesn't seem to exist.

How do I need to write a code so that I can mock the resolved value from `auth().verifyIdToken()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jest mock factory to mock `firebase` module.

```
jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn(),
  }
});
```

Example for spec file:

```
import { auth } from 'firebase-admin';
import Test from './index';

jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn(),
  }
});

describe("Test", () => {
  const email = 'mocked-email@example.com';
  const user = { email, username: 'mocked-username' };

  let mockedAuth: jest.Mock;
  let mockVerifyIdToken: jest.Mock;
  let mockUserService: { findByUsername: jest.Mock }; // mock userService
  let testInstance: Test;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockedAuth = auth as jest.Mock;
    mockVerifyIdToken = jest.fn()
    mockedAuth.mockReturnValue({
      verifyIdToken: mockVerifyIdToken,
    });

    mockUserService = {
      findByUsername: jest.fn(),
    };

    testInstance = new Test(mockUserService);
  });

  test("should return user info when pass correct payload", async () => {
    const payload = 'mocked-payload';

    mockVerifyIdToken.mockResolvedValue({ email });
    mockUserService.findByUsername.mockResolvedValue(user);

    const result = await testInstance.validateUser(payload);

    expect(result).toBe(user);
    expect(mockVerifyIdToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith(payload, true);
    expect(mockUserService.findByUsername).toHaveBeenCalledWith(email);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The trouble in this case is that `auth` and similar exported functions in `firebase-admin` are defined as getters with `Object.defineProperty`. Unfortunately `jest.mock` can't see those when it evaluates the module, so it doesn't add mocks for them.

You'll need to mock `auth` (and any sibling functions you need) in a factory provided to `jest.mock`. Here's how, replacing the `jest.mock` line in your second code snippet:

```
jest.mock('firebase-admin', () =>
{
  const module = jest.createMockFromModule<any>('firebase-admin').default;
  module.auth = jest.fn();
  return module;
});
```

You could also choose to mock `auth`'s return value within that factory to further streamline your code.